# How do you increase speed of this for loop with conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate how many columns for each row have greater than zero values. So if two out of the three columns have the required values then the score is 2.

I can build this using a for loop but it seems to be slow, so I am looking for faster alternatives. How do I do that?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'intro': [1, 2, 3], 'quote': [0, 1, 0],'sample': [0, 1, 4]}, 
                  columns=['intro', 'quote','sample'])

df['score']=0
cols=['intro', 'quote', 'sample']
for i in range(len(df)):
    print(i)
    for col in cols:
        if df.iloc[i][col] >= 1:
            df['score'][i]= df['score'][i]+1
```

```py
df_expected = pd.DataFrame({'intro': [1, 2, 3], 'quote': [0, 1, 0],'sample': [0, 1, 4],'score': [1, 3, 2]}, 
                  columns=['intro', 'quote','sample','score'])
df_expected
```

Comment: How did you calculate your score for row 1 and 2?

Comment: Removing the `print` might already speed up a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will do the trick:

```
df['score']=(df>0).sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a True/False frame of values > 0 like this:

```
df > 0
```

You can coun't the True values in each column using

```
(df > 0).sum(axis)
```

and create a column like this:

```
df['score'] = (df > 0).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: That was so simple and so much faster too for the million rows I have. Thank you!